# How to save TFIDF vectorizer in scikit learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle, tfidfvectorizer

I am developing a **spam classifier** using scikit learn.

Here is my vectorizing code

```py
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(
    analyzer='word', 
    sublinear_tf=True,
    strip_accents='unicode',
    token_pattern=r'\w{1,}',
    ngram_range=(1, 1),
    max_features=10000)


tfidf = vectorizer.fit(data['text'])
features = vectorizer.transform(data['text'])

import pickle
pickle.dump(tfidf, open('tfidf.pickle', 'wb'))
```

Here is what I am doing to predict new input

```py
import joblib

model = joblib.load('model')

vect = pickle.load(open('tfidf.pickle', 'rb'))

new = vect.transform(['some new text...'])

mod.predict(new)
```

When I open vectorizer file **(tfidf.pickle)** and try to predict a new message it shows me the error as

> **ValueError**: X.shape[1] = 7148 should be equal to 38011, the number of features at training time

Answer (score 4):

The error message says that your model expects an input with size 38011, while your TF-IDF vectorizer outputs vectors of dimension 7148. You have a model/preprocessor mismatch here, i.e. your model was trained on vectors that are 38011-dimensional while your TF-IDF outputs vectors that are 7148-dimensional.

A good way to avoid this preprocessing/model mismatch is to use [scikit-learn pipelines](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#pipeline). For instance here you could train your model **and** your TF-IDF vectorizer with the following piece of code (example with a logistic regression here):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import make_pipeline

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(...your TF-IDF arguments...)
model = LogisticRegression(...your model arguments...)
pipeline = make_pipeline(vectorizer, model)

pipeline.fit(X, y)
```

And then you can serialize and load your pipeline with pickle or joblib (e.g. `pickle.dump(pipeline, open('spam_pipeline.pickle', 'wb'))`, then `pipeline = pickle.load(open('spam_pipeline.pickle', 'rb'))` , similarly to what you were already doing.

You can directly use the `predict` method of the pipeline to get a prediction.

Let me know if you need more details.